# Windows 10 and Linux Muparser name allowable character sets are different?

Tags: c++, muparser

In a C++ code using the   muparser-2.2.6.1 I have parser names defined as class hierarchy:

```
ClassA.classB.classC = value
```

This name is parsed correctly on Linux, but rejected **because it contains** "."
on windows 10, because it is outside the "a_szCharset" defined in muparser:

```
parser.DefineNameChars("0123456789_"
                       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

Why the same allowable character set works in Linux and not on Windows?!
How can I extend the name char set and find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I partly answer my question:

I simply added "." in the allowable character set and it works:

void Parser::InitCharSets()
  {
    DefineNameChars( *T("0123456789*.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") );

}

**BUT** I still do not know why it works on Linux out of box...?!

Many thanks for reading.